# All of my MEAN app URL deployed in Heroku has been identified as malicious and/or abusive by facebook in OAuth Redirect URIs facebook login settings

Tags: facebook, heroku, passport-facebook

I've been developing a **MEAN app (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node**) and added Facebook Oauth 2.0. I successfully added Facebook Oauth login and it was working properly before but suddenly all of my Heroku URL was removed in OAuth Redirect URIs facebook login settings and was suddenly treated as malicious and/or abusive.

Facebook Oauth 2.0 was added using Passport Facebook and redirects are
working locally (http://127.0.0.1:3001/client/auth/facebook/callback). I already contacted facebook regarding this but still it's not working.

I've been wondering if anyone here encountered something like this when adding **Heroku** to facebook OAuth Redirect URIs or there has been a bug in **Passport Facebook oauth 2.0**?

My facebook passport code is

```
passport.use('facebook.client', new FacebookStrategy({
// pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
clientID          : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
clientSecret      : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
callbackURL       : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURLOnline,
profileFields     : ["emails", "displayName", "name","timezone", "gender", "profileUrl"],
},
// facebook will send back the token and profile
(token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
// asynchronous
process.nextTick(() => {
    // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
    Client.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, (err, client) => {

        // if there's an error connecting to the database
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        // if the user is found, then log them in
        if (client) {
            return done(null, client); // user found, return that user
        } else {
            // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
            var newClient = new Client();
            // set all of the facebook information in our user model
            newClient.facebook.id         = profile.id; 
            newClient.facebook.token      = token; 
            newClient.facebook.name       = `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`; 
            newClient.facebook.email      = profile.emails[0].value; 
            newClient.facebook.profileUrl = profile.profileUrl; 
            newClient.facebook.gender     = profile.gender; 

            // save our user to the database
            newClient.save(err => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                }
                return done(null, newClient);
            });
        }
    });
});
}));
```

Comment: You can try and report your domain as wrongfully blocked (try and share it on Facebook, in the message you get then there’s a link for that), but chances that helps are rather slim I guess. You should get your own domain name - as long as you are working on just a heroku subdomain(?), you risk getting blocked when other users on that service do shady stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already have a domain in AWS but for development purposes I'm using heroku to reduce cost for deployment. Facebook Passport works on my own domain and is treated as a valid URL as well so it must be a bug at facebook end that my heroku URL was wrongfully blocked. Thank you for your insight.